# How to remove border from table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, border

WordPress 4.1 running Zonya theme.

I want to know how to remove border from table in a wordpress page.
Page link: http://www.worldmarketingsummitgroup.org/partners/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tell us what you have tried, post some example code. Make the question more self contained.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want me to edit the page code or edit the Style.css file?

Comment: No. I suggest you make a smaller version of the problematic code, which shows the problem. So we can understand it without reading through all your code. Then post this here (not in a link), and tell us what you want, and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your style.css add the following to the bottom of the file

```
body:not(woocemmerce-page) .post-content table *
{
border:none!important;
}
```

This is because the current table styling gives each cell (td) a border of 1px.

Comment: Gavin you are one exceptional genius! It worked. I just want to know a little explanation that what this is doing. Like what is this line about :body:not(woocemmerce-page) ?

Comment: Thanks David. Your next step is to mark the question as correct, ie click the tick between the up/down arrows to the left of the answer. You must do this or the question will remain unanswered. Feel free to up-vote as well :)

Comment: The css meaning is this:  Anything in the body that is not  a woocommerce-page, but that is post content containing a table : all elements belonging to that table, apply the border:none. The `!important` bit makes sure it over-rides a previous declaration. I hope that makes sense, cos to me the css itself explains things better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on custom CSS:

```css
table {border: 0px solid #CCC;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
    border: none;
}
```